# CASE Statement without @Query Spring JPA MYSQL

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, case

Is it possible to use CASE statement in SPRING JPA without Explicitly defining the whole query in @Query Annotation.
I have a big query:

```
select m.a, m.b, m.c from Messages m Inner Join Replies r 
on m.message_id = r.message_id
where 
m.message_to = CASE WHEN :#{#filter.messageTo} IS NULL THEN m.messageTo ELSE :#{#filter.messageTo} END  and 
m.txt_mode = CASE WHEN :#{#filter.textMode} IS NULL THEN m.txt_mode ELSE :#{#filter.textMode} END 
order by date desc, messageTo, message_id desc limit 100
```

Can the above query be somehow framed using annotations or method names like:
`findAllbyMessageToDescAndTextModeDescLimit100(Filters)` for the CASE statement as well?
Also I have more than 10 filters appending everything into Method would make the method very long, Is there any way I can reduce this and not just hardcode the whole query in @Query annotation and let JPA handle it?

Comment: `where (m.message_to =  :#{#filter.messageTo} or  :#{#filter.messageTo} is null) and ...`